# Need to create this table with the DBO

Tags: sql-server

I am creating this table in the database, only issue is, it creates as
dbo.OPTC.ZIP_ALLZIPCODES

```
How to create this without the dbo?

  CREATE TABLE [OPTC.ZIP_ALLZIPCODES](
    [ZIPCODE] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [CITY] [nvarchar](28) NULL,
    [STATEABBREVIATION] [nvarchar](2) NULL
) ON [CODES]
```

Comment: I assume you want this in the schema OPTC? The square brackets mean your table name is OPTC.ZIP_ALLZIPCODES and will be created in the default schema since there is no schema specified. You don't need the square brackets here. CREATE TABLE OPTC.ZIP_ALLZIPCODES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work, you have to use [] before the `.`

```
CREATE TABLE [OPTC].[ZIP_ALLZIPCODES](
[ZIPCODE] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
[CITY] [nvarchar](28) NULL,
[STATEABBREVIATION] [nvarchar](2) NULL
) ON [CODES]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make OPTC be the schema instead of DBO, try this:

```
  CREATE TABLE [OPTC].[ZIP_ALLZIPCODES](
    [ZIPCODE] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [CITY] [nvarchar](28) NULL,
    [STATEABBREVIATION] [nvarchar](2) NULL
) ON [CODES]
```